# Bash Replace value with string code

Tags: bash, replace

I have two files that go like this:

file1(reference file)
BBB;33
AAA;2
CCC;5

file2
5;.;.;.
33;.;.;.

I would like to replace the corresponding string in the first column of the file 1 with the corresponding value in column1 file 2 so to have:

output
CCC;.;.;.
BBB;.;.;.

Hope this is clear,

Thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly and the order is correct in the files,

```
$ cat file1
BBB;33
AAA;2
CCC;5
$ cat file2
33;.;.;.
2;.;.;.
5;.;.;.
$ paste file1 file2 | sed 's/\([0-9]\+\)\t\1;//'
BBB;.;.;.
AAA;.;.;.
CCC;.;.;.
```

Add `> file3` to the last command to write the output to `file3`. Then you can do `mv file3 file1`.

Comment: Actually, *don't* add `> file1` to the last command, as that will overwrite `file1` before `paste` gets a chance to read it.

Comment: thanks. Seem to work more or less but the output format is not in the correct form. Maybe I should have mentioned that both file are `;` separated.

Comment: @g256 You probably should have. If you edit the question to show the file, format, I'll make the corresponding changes to my answer (don't forget to ping me here if you do).

Comment: @Lev Levitsky Sorry. I have just changed the format in the question.

Comment: @g256 look like you only need to add a `;` in the command, see the edit.

Comment: Uhm...the output is still strange. Maybe it's because the order of the file1 is not equal to the order of file2 and could also be that some codes that needs to be replace in file2 are not present as a number in file2. Any idea to handle with that would be great. I will change the example in a more general way. Thanks.

Comment: @Lev Levitsky.The reference file contains all the name, but not all of this are contained as a number in file2. Hope this is clear.